# I am trying to collect image metadata and I am gettng this error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, computer-forensics

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

# path to the image or video
imagename=input("Enter image path:")

# read the image data using PIL
image=Image.open(imagename)

# extract EXIF data
exifdata=image.getexif()

# in exifdata , all fields are id's not a human readable form
#  iterate over all EXIF data fields

# print(exifdata)
for tag_id in exifdata:
    # get tag name, instead of human unreadavle tag id
    tag=TAGS.get(tag_id,tag_id)
    data=exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # decode bytes
    if isinstance(data,bytes):
        data=data.decode()
        print(f"{tag:25}:{data}")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image_metadata.py", line 23, in 
data=data.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 1: invalid continuation byte

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQj9M.png)

Comment: Only specific EXIF tags contain string data; calling `.decode()` on tags containing numeric data is inappropriate.

Comment: `exiftool` is the best way to look at EXIF data, IMHO.